# Term used to prove someone ungrateful

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the term used in English when you want to insult or humiliate someone reminding them of the previous favour in an attempt to prove them ungrateful?

Comment: Do you mean 'What do you call that person?' or 'How do you describe the situation?'

Answer (score 1):

You could say “You owe me (one).” This means you did something nice for them before and now they have a “debt” to you.

Just for clarity, this is not a very nice thing to say. It is impolite to do a favor with the expectation of getting something in return.

Answer (score 0):

One such term could be "*thankless wretch*" or "*how ungrateful*". It is quite tricky to find something that "reminds them of the previous favour".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convey this idea, you could just say, "Ingrate!"

Lexico defines it as "An ungrateful person", and terms it literary or formal.  To me it does not seem to be either of these, but I will concede that it is seldom heard.

Comment: While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].